# Question about two sub bases generating a topology

Tags: general-topology

For the following questions, is it asking me to show the two subbgases generate the same topoloy.  If so, do I show that both subbases are both a base for the topology X and that each is a subset of the other.

Let $\mathcal{L_1}$ and $\mathcal{L_2}$ be collections of subsets of a set $X$ such that $X= \cup\{S\in\mathcal{L_1}\} = \cup\{S\in\mathcal{L_2}\}.$  Moreover, suppose that:

(1)  for each $S_1 \in\mathcal{L_1}$ and for each $x\in S_1$ there exists $S_2 \in\mathcal{L_2}$ such that $x\in S_2$ and $S_2 \subset S_1,$ and

(2)  for each $S_2 \in\mathcal{L_2}$ and for each $x\in S_2$ there exists $S_1 \in\mathcal{L_1}$ such that $x\in S_1$ and $S_1 \subset S_2.$

Then $\mathcal{L_1}$, $\mathcal{L_2}$ are subbases for the same topology on X.

The definition for a sub-basis is as follows:

Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be a topological space.  A subcollection $\mathcal{L}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ is a subbasis for $\mathcal{F}$ provided the family of all finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{F}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{F}.$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation: $[A]^{<\omega}$ is the set of finite subsets of $A.$

For $i\in \{1,2\}$ let $T_i$ be the topology generated by the sub-base $L_i.$ Then $B_i=\{\cap S:S\in [L_i]^{<\omega}\}$ is a base for $T_i.$

If $i\in \{1,2\}$ and $x\in U_i\in T_i$ then there exists $b\in B_i$ with $x\in b\subset U_i,$ and  there exists $S\in  [L_i]^{<\omega}$ such that $\cap S=b.$  This requires $x\in \sigma\in L_i$ for each $\sigma \in S.$

Now the hypothesis implies that for each $\sigma  \in S$ we may take $\sigma'\in L_{3-i}$ with $x\in \sigma'\subset  \sigma.$

So let $U_{3-i}=\cap \{\sigma':\sigma\in S\}.$

We have $x\in U_{3-i}\subset \cap S=b\subset U_i.$

We have $\{\sigma':\sigma \in S\}\in [L_{3-i}]^{<\omega},$ so $U_{3-i}\in B_{3-i}\subset T_{3-i}.$ So we have $U_{3-i}\in T_{3-i}.$

So whenever $i\in {1,2}$ and $x\in U_i\in T_i$ there exists $U_{3-i}\in T_{3-i}$ such that $x\in U_{3-i}\subset U_i.$

With $i=1$ this implies $T_1\subset T_2$ and with $i=2$ this implies $T_2\subset T_1.$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  My apologies for my late reply.

Comment: On this site, I don't consider one day as "late"..... I considered showing by the same method that whenever $i\in \{1,2\}$ and $x\in b\in B_i$ there exists $b'\in B_{3-i}$ such that $x\in b'\subset b$ (which suffices to imply $T_1=T_2$) but  it was not needed... BTW the notation $[A]^{<\omega}$ is from Set Theory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

**Hint:** Specifically, you have to prove from the conditions that any finite intersection $\cap_{i\le n} S_i$ with $S_i\in\mathcal L_1$ is a union of sets of the form $\cap_{i\le k} T_i$ with $T_i\in\mathcal L_2$ and $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: do you mean I have to show the following:  $\bigcap_i^n  \mathcal{S_i}= \bigcup \{\bigcap_i^k \mathcal{T_i}\}$

Comment: No, not that simple. Cf the other answer.